# How can I copy a file from one dir to another with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have the code:

```
xcopy /s C:\Documents and Setting\WindowsXP-VM\Desktop\USB\* to C:\Documents and Setting\WindowsXP-VM\Desktop\startup

pause
```

Saved in a .bat file and when I run it it says **Invalid Number of Parameters** I have looked on google for abit and cant figure this out I even tried putting the dest in quotes and that gave me another error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces are throwing things off; wrap your paths in quotes:

```
xcopy /s "C:\Documents and Setting\WindowsXP-VM\Desktop\USB\*" "C:\Documents and Setting\WindowsXP-VM\Desktop\startup"

pause
```

Comment: Still not working: Invalid Number of Parameters 0 Files copied now

Comment: @Mike -- sorry, I left the "to" in between the paths, which should have been removed.  Please try again.

Comment: Yes! You guys rock thanks so much I hate asking you guys over silly things like this but I could not figure it out for the life of me. Thanks got it working!

Comment: @Ashok Felix - the syntax you attempted to edit in was invalid; do not edit answers if you don't know the syntax.